# Vuejs my own component not working with empty v-mask

Tags: vuejs2

I've created a component with an input that uses v-mask directive. But if the mask is empty the input not display the characters when I type. Anyone can help me?

this is my input code

```
<input
      :type="type"
      :name="name"
      class="vs-inputx vs-input--input normal"
      :value="value"
      :disabled="disabled"
      v-on="inputListeners"
      v-mask="mask"
    />
```

and in the props I have this

```
props: {
  mask: {
    type: String,
    default: ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal Code example that reproduces the described behavior.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot that. Now I put the code.

Comment: Do you use vue-the-mask Plugin? v-mask is not a buildin directive. The Plugin behaves as it should. `mask=''` means no input allowed at all.

Comment: No, I'm using VueMask (https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-mask)